# How to run a 'INSERT INTO SELECT" with 2 databases in Perl?

Tags: perl, dbi

Since each mysql statement in Perl is linked to its connection handler :

```
my $handlerDB1 = DBI->connect(etc ...);
my $handlerDB2 = DBI->connect(etc ...);
```

I wonder if there's a trick to do a

```
INSERT INTO tableDB2
SELECT * FROM tableDB1;
```

And if not, what would be the simpler way to get and insert these data ?

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**=== Update**

In hindsight, you can do it with `->execute_for_fetch`, alas this looks a bit clumsy and slow

https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute_for_fetch

From the docs:

```
my $sel = $dbh1->prepare("select foo, bar from table1");
$sel->execute;
 
my $ins = $dbh2->prepare("insert into table2 (foo, bar) values (?,?)");
my $fetch_tuple_sub = sub { $sel->fetchrow_arrayref };
 
my @tuple_status;
$rc = $ins->execute_for_fetch($fetch_tuple_sub, \@tuple_status);
my @errors = grep { ref $_ } @tuple_status;
```

**=== Original**

I asked a similar question on perlmonks recently:

[DBI/MySQL/MariaDB clone tables across DB Connections](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=11150394)

I'm not aware of MySQL allowing communication cross db-handles, and DBI doesn't seem to cover this case. (wait, see update)

You need to dump the data from the first connection and load it to the second.

You may wanna do it in memory instead filesystem.

In both cases using intermediate temporary SQL tables on both sides may help transporting a sub query.

Comment: Thank you lanX, I inderstand the principle of execute_for_fetch, despite I don't understand the last statement with "ref" . I'm going to test it, hoping that these bundled commands handle in a good way null values in column, avoiding to handle them when doing a select + insert manually. I'll tell you.

Comment: It's a bulk operation with a call-back in  `$fetch_tuple_sub` which is called for each row, to get the tuple to be inserted (actually the docs say that for better performance it might be buffering the results for multiple rows).  

Each individual result is held in  `@tuple_status` and array-refs mean it's an error.  The `grep` is filtering those in `@error` ( [ref](https://perldoc.pl/functions/ref) will be false for non-references). 

Everything went fine if `@error` is empty.

Comment: Great, thank you for your accurate explanation !

Comment: Heum .... Perl add \' ...\' to quote values, and something seems to not be standard :  
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'insert into new_table value (\'410\',\'1\',\'0\',\'1\',\'\',\'(?is)always .*\',\'\',\' at line 1',

Comment: My bad ... I check

Comment: Ok it works :) performance is just not amazing ....

Comment: As I said I didn't expect it to be fast. But it's generic, you can do all cross server operations with that. Now, if performance matters, you can always use SQL Dump operations. And if it has to be done inside Perl maybe try to transfer the whole data in just one statement into a temporary table, and than operate only on the target server. But all this is not a Perl topic anymore. :)